# Why does to_json escape unicode automatically in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, encoding, unicode, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 3:

```
{"a" => "<br/>"}.to_json
=> "{\"a\":\"<br/>\"}"
```

Rails 4:

```
{"a" => "<br/>"}.to_json
=> "{\"a\":\"\\u003Cbr/\\u003E\"}"
```

WHY???

It appears to be causing the error

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

When my Rails 3 app tries to parse JSON generated by my rails 4 app.

Comment: Try this: JSON.generate({"a" => "<br/>"}, :ascii_only => true)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> WHY???

To defend against a common weakness in web applications. If you say in an HTML page eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something = <%= @something.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

then you might think you're fine because you've JSON-escaped the data you're injecting into JavaScript. But actually you're not safe: aside from JSON syntax you also have surrounding HTML syntax, and in an HTML script block `</` is in-band signalling. Practically, if `@something` contains the string `</script>` you've got a cross-site scripting vulnerability as this comes out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var something = {"attack": "abc</script><script>alert('XSS');//"};
</script>
```

The first script block ends halfway through the string (leaving an unclosed string literal syntax error) and the second `<script>` is treated as a new script block and the potentially-user-submitted content within it executed.

Escaping the `<` character to `\u003C` is not required by JSON but it is a perfectly valid alternative and it automatically avoids this class of problems. If a JSON parser rejects it, that is a severe bug in the reader.

What is the code that is producing that error? I'm not convinced the error is anything to do with the `<`-escaping, as it is talking about byte 0xC3 rather than 0x3C. That could be indicative of a string with UTF-8 encoded content not having been marked as UTF-8... maybe you need a `force_encoding("UTF-8")` on the input?

Comment: If you really need to disable the JSON escaping (assuming your situation is safe from injection) you can do so with:
`ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = false`

Comment: In your example, why does calling `.html_safe` not entity-escape the "</script>" to "&lt;/script&gt;"? What does this method do?

Comment: `html_safe` actually does the opposite, it marks the string as containing raw markup which the caller has already guaranteed is safe so doesn't need further escaping. If you *don't* mark the string `html_safe` then Rails automatically escapes it (since Rails 3).

Answer (score 12):

You can retain the original string with `JSON::dump`:

```
JSON::dump "a" => "<br/>"
=> "{\"a\":\"<br/>\"}"

JSON::dump "a" => "x&y"
=> {\"a\":\"x&y\"}" # instead of x\u0026y
```

Use it with care for the reasons bobince mentions and particularly avoid it with any user-generated input (or at least make sure that's sanitized).

Here's an example I encountered where it's a legitimate use. Generating a JavaScript hash argument in a helper function:

```
# application_helper.rb

def widget_js(post)
  options = {
    color: ColorCalculator(post.color).to_rgb_hex,
    ...
  }
  "third_party_widget(#{JSON::dump options});"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this issue too and as others have mentioned, it's caused by using the ActiveSupport to_json method. To resolve, use the JSON gem directly with JSON.generate(data) where data is an Array or Hash. See https://github.com/flori/json for all JSON gem documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar problem with Rails 7 sending "<" in JSON output like:

`..., "legend":[{"text":"<96.8%","color":"#FFAFFF"},{"text":"96.8% to 98.8%","color":"#E37DE3"},{"text":"98.8% to 100%","color":"#BA50BA"}], ...`

from something like:

`{entry: dataset.entry, legend: dataset.legend, ...`

The "<" sign was showing up `"legend":[{"text":"\u003c96.8%", ...`

In my case `JSON.generate({entry: ...})` fixed the issue