# Prevent Rails from encoding the ampersands in a URL when outputting JSON

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, ampersand

I have the following code:

```
render json: { image: image }
```

Image has an attribute "url". Let's say it's:

```
https://blah.com/a?A=B&C=D
```

When rendering, this is what I get:

```
{"image":{"url":"https://blah.com/a?A=B\u0026C=D"}}
```

The ampersand is getting encoded as \u0026

Is there any way to avoid this encoding?

Comment: See my answer to this similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35020478/594763

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Add to your **application.rb** file:

```
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
```

Comment: And don't forget to restart server after :-) ..nice answer!

Comment: This opens up your application to XSS vulnerabilities if you render data somewhere from that JSON https://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/cross_site_scripting_to_json/

Answer (score -1):

your answer described there:

[Converting URL to JSON version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494255/converting-url-to-json-version)

[JSON encoding wrongly escaped (Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123993/json-encoding-wrongly-escaped-rails-3-ruby-1-9-2)

[Why does is Rails 4 unicode escaping in to_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936318/why-does-is-rails-4-unicode-escaping-in-to-json)

[Encoding JSON in href using encodeURI, Rails parsing (article)](https://coderwall.com/p/5a3-ha/encoding-json-in-href-using-encodeuri-rails-parsing)

and also this would help you:

[Jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

Comment: All these explain why it happens, but not how to solve the problem. The URLs i have are to external resources, not internal to my app, so I can't solve this problem by using the routing helpers to generate URLs. And monkeypatching sounds like a very, very bad idea.

Comment: Can you paste part of your code?  Or explain your problem more? where you use these codes? ...