# encode & decode URL params in rails api pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, encoding, decoding, url-parameters

In my rails-api app, a user can request for products index by pagination.

So I want to provide next and previous url via paging hash as

```
result = @products.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => params[:per_page] || 5)

paging {
    :next => www.url.com?page=next&per_page=5,
    :prev => www.url.com?page=prev&per_page=5,
}

result << paging
render json: result
```

The above data i.e. paging hash is sent as `www.url.com?page=2\u0026per_page=5`

Hence, when this request comes, page and per_page params aren't recognised.

How do I resolve this??

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was `render json: result`.

`json method` was converting the `&` symbol. So I had to add following line in `application.rb` file

```
config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = false
```

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27460529/1129470).